# SteamID Конвертер

Tags: php, php7

скажите пожалуйста, есть ли у кого то конвертер SteamID64 в SteamID. Все решения что есть в интернете очень старые и не подходят под PHP 7 и далее.
`<?=$steam64['steamid']?>` - здесь я получаю SteamID64
Как мне дальше преобразовать в SteamID формата STEAM_0: и так далее и вывести его на страницу ну допустим под переменной $steamid32?
В интернете куча решений, но ни одного под PHP 7

UPD: Пробовал вот этот код
Сама библиотека:

```
<?php
class SteamIDConverter {
    public static function convert($id)
    {
        if(strpos($id, 'STEAM')===false) 
        { // It's a CommunityID
            return self::getIDFromCommunity($id);
        }
        else
        { // It's a SteamID
            return self::getCommunityFromID($id);
        }
    }
    private  static function getCommunityFromID($id)
    {
        $accountarray   =   explode(":", $id);
        $idnum          =   $accountarray[1];
        $accountnum     =   $accountarray[2];
        $constant       =   '76561197960265728';
        $number         =   bcadd(bcmul($accountnum, 2), bcadd($idnum, $constant)); // ($accountnum *2) + ($idnum + $constant)
        return $number;
    }
    private static function getIDFromCommunity($id)
    {
        $idnum      =   '0';
        $accnum     =   '0';
        $constant   =   '76561197960265728';
        if(bcmod($id, '2')==0)
        {
            $idnum  =   '0';
            $temp   =   bcsub($id, $constant);
        }
        else
        {
            $idnum  =   '1';
            $temp   =   bcsub($id,bcadd($constant, '1'));
        }
        $accnum =   bcdiv($temp, '2');
        return      "STEAM_0:".$idnum.":".number_format($accnum, 0, '', '');
    }
}
```

И функция вывода

`echo SteamIDConverter::convert('$steam64');`

Но выводит вот такие ошибки

Warning: bcmod(): bcmath function argument is not well-formed in /var/www/u1087147/data/www/u-reborn.site/SteamIDConverter.php on line 55

Warning: bcsub(): bcmath function argument is not well-formed in /var/www/u1087147/data/www/u-reborn.site/SteamIDConverter.php on line 58

Выводит вот это:

STEAM_0:0:-38280598980132864

Что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код работает правильно, но конвертирует ид не верно, либо просто он устарел и способ изменился либо некогда работал.

```
private static function getIDFromCommunity($id)
{
    $id = intval($id);
    $idnum      =   0;
    $accnum     =   0;
    $constant   =   76561197960265728;
    if(($id % 2)==0)
    {
        $idnum  =   0;
        $temp   =   $id - $constant;
    }
    else
    {
        $idnum  =   1;
        $temp   =   $id - ($constant + 1);
    }
    $accnum =   $temp / 2;
    return      "STEAM_0:".$idnum.":".number_format($accnum, 0, '', '');
}
```

Вот так у меня мой ид конвертирует верно

```
private static function getIDFromCommunity($id)
{
    $id = intval($id);
    $idnum = ($id % 2) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    $constant   =   76561197960265728;
    return      "STEAM_0:".$idnum.":".number_format(($id - $constant), 0, '', '');
}
```

Comment: Странно, я ощущаю себя сейчас идиотом, у которого ничего не получается. Ну я как бы сделал так, как вы сказали. Да, он изменил значение в отличие от предыдущего, но STEAM_0:0:-76561197960265728 это не то, что я хотел получить.

Comment: На вход этой функции вы что подаете ?

Comment: Пытаюсь подать значение $steam64['steamid'], но при этом происходит ошибка
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'steamid' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /var/www/u1087147/data/www/u-reborn.site/player-area.php on line 132
Пытаюсь подать просто $steam64 - выводит фигню, а если вставить туда просто число Steam64, то в принципе конвертирует верно

Comment: Все верно, в функцию передавайте число staeam64, не строку

Comment: Вот написал класс, можете посмотреть в работе https://implode.io/uHenv9

Comment: А как мне сделать так, чтобы мне использовать `<?=$steam64['steamid']?>`. Мне не нужно просто вставлять число - у меня немного не тот смысл использования. Мне нужно сконвертировать `<?=$steam64['steamid']?>`. А потом это сконвертированное число записать допустим в какую либо переменную и потом ее использовать. Если знаете как, можете подсказать?

Comment: $steamid = SteamIDConverter::Steam64To32($steam64['steamid']);